# Using ADO to join and query text files

Tags: join, text-files, ado

I just assumed this could be done, but I'm starting to wonder. The first thing is I'm noticing it won't take the syntax I would normally use, even with a single table (just trying to get down to the simplest possible syntax)

```
Select [file_name.txt].[fieldname] From [file_name.txt]
```

" is not a valid name - this is the error I get. I could just remove the filename qualifier from the field and it would be fine, however, when I do go to join, I would normally need to use this kind of syntax in the join portion:

```
Inner Join [file_name2.txt] On [file_name.txt].[fieldname]=[file_name2.txt].[fieldname]
```

in which case it will tell err out for "invalid bracketing of [file_name.txt].[fieldname]"

I'm not sure why this is a problem. If I try taking out the filename qualifiers here, I get a "join expression not supported" error.

My schema.ini looks like this:

```
[file_name.txt]
Format=Delimited(|)
ColNameHeader=True

[file_name2.txt]
Format=Delimited(|)
ColNameHeader=True
```

My connection string is:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="C:\Path"
;Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes"""
```

So I'm wondering if this is even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible and it works. I was intrigued by your question so I tried it out myself. The text driver doesn't understand the bracketing on the fieldnames, only on the table name.

So use aliases for the field names like this:

```
Select tb1.[fieldname], tb2.[fieldname] From [file_name.txt] as tb1
Inner Join [file_name2.txt] as tb2
On tb1.[fieldname]=tb2.[fieldname]
```

What worked for me:

```
SELECT tb1.[Month], tb2.[Year] FROM [Text;DATABASE=E:\].[MoneyAndCreditStats 0409 to 0417.csv] as tb1
 INNER JOIN  [Text;DATABASE=E:\].[StackaOverFlowTest.csv] as tb2 ON
tb2.[Month] = tb1.[Month] AND
tb1.[Year] = tb2.[Year]
```

Text driver is a nifty tool especially when shuffling data formats/files around for Business Intelligence.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, at leas your example is. I did find the same answer elsewhere. Note though that the explanation is not what you meant to say I believe. The text driver in this case understands brackets only around field names, so you have to use an alias for the joins.

Comment: Yes. Typo on my part. Apologies. Should have been "fieldnames". Have amended the answer